# Load several files into spark-sql from SQL shell

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load a directory's worth of files (no recursion) into Spark-SQL, from the `spark-sql>` shell.

My query is roughly:

```
CREATE TABLE table  
USING org.apache.spark.sql.parquet  
OPTIONS (  
    path "s3://bucket/folder/*"  
);
```

Cheers.

edit:

`"s3:/bucket/"` seems to recursively load everything. I now have the issue whereby I cannot use wildcards in the url. So `s3://bucket/*/month=06"` gives a 'No such file or directory' `FileNotFoundException`.